# Accessing js object issue

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created an object of available_categories({category: coats-and-jackets}) and another object category_names_for_display({coats-and-jackets:Coats and Jackets}).

The intention is to use the 'key' (coats-and-jackets) from the loop of available_categories, to get the category_name_for_display (Coats & Jackets) from the second object.

```
// build array of available categories
var obj = available_categories.find(o=>o.category === cat);
if (!(obj) && cat && cat.length > 0) {
    available_categories.push({
        category: cat
    });
}
//console.log('ac=' + available_categories);

// build array of category_names_for_display  
var obj = category_names_for_display.find(o=>o.cat === category_name_for_display);
if (!obj && cat && cat.length > 0 && category_name_for_display) {
    console.log('cat = ' + cat + 'cnfd= ' + category_name_for_display);

var arr = {};
arr[cat] = category_name_for_display;
category_names_for_display.push(arr);

new_var = category_names_for_display['cat'];
console.log('this  ' + new_var);
}
if (available_categories.length > 0) {

    //loop through the array to output more data
    $.each(available_categories, function(k , v) 
    {

        $.each(this, function(k , v) 
        {
            var checked_status = '';
            var selected_option_number = '';
            var undo_label = '';
            console.log('k=   ' + k + 'V=   ' + v);

            // here is where I have something wrong :(
            var catego = category_names_for_display['v'];

        }

    }

}
```

I am only getting the console to show the value is undefined. I need the category_name_for_display to be Coats & Jackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create a object and push.

```
if ( !obj && cat && cat.length > 0 && category_name_for_display )
{
  var arr = {};
  arr[cat] = category_name_for_display;
  category_names_for_display.push(arr);
}
```

Comment: I've added a console.log submission which tends to suggest the data isn't being put into the object.  Or the method of retrieving the data from a hash is incorrect.  I know it's Monday but this is unusually frustrating. :rolleyes:  @Ajay

Answer (score 0):

`category_names_for_display` is an `array` and the mistake is you are trying to access `category_names_for_display` as an `object`

You can modify you code as shown below to make your `var catego` store corect thing

```
 $.each(this, function(k , v)
{
    var checked_status = '';
    var selected_option_number = '';
    var undo_label = '';
    console.log('k=   ' + k + 'V=   ' + v);

    var catego = category_names_for_display.find(item => item === v);

}
```

Comment: It's better to keep the keys and labels as an object, like `{coats-and-jackets: 'Coats and Jackets', 'cap-and-shoes': 'Cap and shoes'}` It's easily accessible and you can avoid unnecessary loop.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the coding above to reflect that, which I understand to be, your advice.  However, I still get undefined for the var, catego